# Devise throws undefined user for nil class in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I am using the [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) in version 3.2.2 for authentication in my Rails 3.2.17 app. Now I am building an API and securing it with devise using the method suggested in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6).

Now when I am doing a get request on a secured controller using curl (in this case with a UI) I get a 200 and the response I was looking for. For some reasons my tests fail and produce an error like this:

```
1) Api::V1::UsersController#information should get the dancing partner
 Failure/Error: get :information, {}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb:26:in `authenticate_user_from_token!'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/users_controller_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't know if this is an issue caused by devise or by something else, so I attached all changed code at the bottom of this post.

Here is an example how it should work:

[image]

[This is my Api controller, which should secure the normal controllers used for the api.](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/turnierApp/blob/2cc0c179c8303868e3bb23bc08fd1c9317c7a970/app/controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb)

[This is my secured controller](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/turnierApp/blob/2cc0c179c8303868e3bb23bc08fd1c9317c7a970/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb)

[Here are my tests](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/turnierApp/blob/2cc0c179c8303868e3bb23bc08fd1c9317c7a970/spec/controllers/api/users_controller_spec.rb)

[This is my authentication helper](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/turnierApp/blob/2cc0c179c8303868e3bb23bc08fd1c9317c7a970/spec/support/auth_helpers.rb)

[This is my test helper](https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/turnierApp/blob/2cc0c179c8303868e3bb23bc08fd1c9317c7a970/spec/spec_helper.rb)

[The complete output of log/test.log](http://pastebin.com/d6vc9dGj)

Comment: What is `get :information, {}` intended to do?  Is that similar to `visit information_path` ?

Comment: ```get :information, {}``` is the same as ```get information_path```. visit is a method of capybara, which opens the page, I think with webdriver. get just sends a HTTP GET request to the given path

Comment: Start by getting a more detailed stack trace.  Rspec (and Capybara, probably) only shows the lines of the stack trace that are in your code, not those in gems.  So replace the failing line of code with: `begin; `+failing_line_of_code_here+`rescue => e; puts e.backtrace.join("\n"); raise e; end` and you'll be able to figure out where the error is actually coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out, that this error came from accessing the user variable at a point, where I was testing the response for an invalid authentication.